# Forklift simulation

Tags: java, android, box2d

I am trying to implement forklift in my game, I have some troubles though, with creating objects with might be moved/picked with those forklifts, here is image to explain it better:

[image]

In such example, if player would like to put forklift platform under the box to lift it, bodies would simply collide, and my question is, any idea how to handle it properly?

I had one idea, to make box body - to build it with multiple fixtures like that:

[image]

Description of the body is on the image, explained clearly I hope, I suppose it would be solution. But maybe there is another one, easier? Because this one would force me to create custom body with multiple fixtures for every movable objects, which would be bit bad idea.

Thanks.

Comment: you need a pallet ...  LOL.  no, seriously.  if the object the box sits on is a pallet, then the fork can penetrate under

Comment: Agreed with @foampile - in the real world forklifts generally lift objects sitting on pallets. Just change the design so any moveable object is on a pallet then you only have to implement the inner/outer body for the pallet object and not all the other objects.

Comment: the @foampile suggestion is a good one. You could also do it the other way around and make the fork prong not collide with the ground. It might look a bit strange but would avoid the work of having to set up special spacer fixtures on everything that the forklift should be able to pick up.

Comment: Use clamp attachment with your forklift.  Save money if pallet is not requirement by customer. I'm not kidding, I used to develop warehouse management systems :P